# Open exe file using VBA

Tags: vba, shell

I wanted to open a file by VBA and I've written this code:

```vb
ShellExecute ("explorer.exe C:\FY20 CPM\HS-HO-OPG\B -  SQL INDIRECT BUSINESS\FP 201801\sde.exe")
```

And for every file it works if I give there notepad or something like this, it will work, for example:

```vb
ShellExecute ("explorer.exe C:\FY20 CPM\HS-HO-OPG\B -  SQL INDIRECT BUSINESS\FP 201801\Test.txt")
```

But for that first code, I'm getting this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\sde-query.log' is denied.

[image: Error]

What I want to underline is that I can normally open this file manually. This file is something like SQL making some queries.

So it is probably a problem with UnauthorizedAccess.
Is there any stronger function than shell? For exmaple open as administator or something?
Or maybe someone has a better idea on how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it appears that the executable that you're trying to run generates its log files in the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Now, the code that you posted doesn't make much sense. It looks like you're launching Explorer.exe and passing the path of the target file as an argument. In which case, your code should probably be `ShellExecute "explorer.exe", "C:\FY20..."` instead of `ShellExecute "explorer.exe C:\FY20..."`.

Anyway, the problem with this is that because `ShellExecute` is actually launching `Explorer.exe`, not `sde.exe`, the working directory becomes the system32 directory which the `sde.exe` process doesn't have permission to access, hence, the `UnauthorizedAccessException`. To prevent this, you should launch `sde.exe` directly without `Explorer.exe`. Here's a complete example:

```vb
Dim filePath As String
filePath = "C:\FY20 CPM\HS-HO-OPG\B -  SQL INDIRECT BUSINESS\FP 201801\sde.exe"

Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
objShell.ShellExecute filePath, "", "", "open", 1
Set objShell = Nothing
```

And you can even change the working directory by passing a path to the third parameter:

```vb
Dim customWorkingDir As String
customWorkingDir = "C:\FY20 CPM\HS-HO-OPG\B -  SQL INDIRECT BUSINESS\FP 201801"
objShell.ShellExecute filePath, "", customWorkingDir , "open", 1
```

---

### References:

- [ShellExecute method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-shellexecute).

Comment: Hello, sorry for delay,

Problem why You were suprised with my code was becuase I used Shell, not ShellExecute. No idea why I said ShellExecute when I posted it, probably becuase I tried this option after use google xD

Btw thanks for Your help, I got ur point but, your code doesn't work for me.
I recorded a film, what happens: https://megawrzuta.pl/download/8cbcb9feab9159c1cb767398d27cbfe9.html

And I can see in log that nothing has happen.